# Threading - wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

The `wait()` method on an object can be called only in the synchronized context i.e. the current thread must have a lock on the object to invoke the `wait()` method. Now if a thread T1 has a lock on an object(`obj`) and invokes its wait method `obj.wait()` . How can other threads get lock on this object(`obj`) so that they can also call wait, which is already possessed T1 ?

Answer (score 9):

`wait` releases the synchronized context. From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread **releases
>   ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up (...)

Comment: Yeah, the synchronized block goes into a half-lock, where other threads can acquire the lock. Because the synchronized block is around both statements, the woken thread 'joins' the synchronized context, and there is no chance for 'locked' resources to be accessed outside of the context.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to be synchronized for the duration of calling the wait() method, not for the duration of the wait time.